# Power series - interval of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

For

$f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^n}{n(n-1)}$

I have showed that $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^n}{n}$ and that $f''(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ at all points where f converges absolutely. ( f converges absolutely whenever $\vert x + 1\vert < 1$. )

I now have to prove that $f(x)=1+x-xln(-x)$ on the convergence interval. I tried to do this by doing the following $f'(x) = \int -1/x~dx = -ln(x)$ and then I used this result to get 
 $f(x) = \int -ln(x)~dx= x-xln(x)$.

But this is not correct and I cannot see what I did wrong.

Comment: You need to be carefull about the bounds of your integral: $f^\prime(x) - f^\prime(a) = -\int_a^x \frac{dt}{t}$, for some $a$ that has to be in the disc of convergence of $f$. $(a=1$ is *not* a valid choice. for instance)

Comment: You are quite close. The integral of $\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ is $\ln(|x|)+C$. Since $x$ is negative we have $|x|=-x$. The remaining trouble is the constant. Your integral should really be a definite integral, from $t=-1$ to $x$. That will make the constant right.

Comment: Another way: Let $x+1=t$. Note that $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$ and recognize $\sum \frac{t^n}{n}$ and $\sum \frac{t^n}{n-1}$.

Comment: Okay, so I have tried again and I think I got it but I am still not sure. 

I have $\int -1/x~dx = -ln(\vert x \vert)$  and since x < 0 I have -ln(-x) because if it was x > 0 then I wouldn't have convergence. Now I have $\int_{-1}^x -ln(-x)~dx = (x - x ln(-x))-(-1 +ln(1))= 1+x-xln(-x)$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Did I do it right now?

Comment: Yes, you did it right. You were basically always on the right track. The minus signs caused some trouble, as did the fact you didn't quite know that a definite integral was involved. Indefinite integral will also work, but then you you need to put in a constant of integration, and evaluate it by noting that the function value at $-1$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the question has been settled in comments, we give another way to evaluate the sum.

Let $t=x+1$, and use the partial fractions decomposition $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$ to rewrite our sum as
$$\sum_2^\infty \frac{t^n}{n-1} -\sum_2^\infty \frac{t^n}{n}.$$
The first sum is $\sum_1^\infty t\cdot \frac{t^k}{k}$.  We know that the series for $\ln(1-t)$ is $\sum_1^\infty \frac{t^k}{k}$, so our first series is $t\ln(1-t)$.  The second series is easier, just $\ln(1-t)$ with first term missing, so $\ln t-t$.

We end up with $t\ln (1-t)-\ln(1-t)+t$. Now put $t=x+1$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome. The main task was to fix the minor glitches in what you had done. By the way, you should have said that the series converges absolutely for $|x+1|\le 1$, the boundary is fine too because of the $n^2$-like denominator.

Comment: Hello, sorry for bothering you with this exercise again. I have one question, how do we know that the series for $ln(1-t)$ is $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{t^k}{k}$? I cannot seem to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Two ways. We can use the Maclaurin expansion, the derivatives are pretty easy. Or else we can recall that (infinite geometric series) we have $\frac{1}{1-u}=1+u+u^2+u^3+u^4+\cdots$. Integrate from $u=0$ to $u=t$. On the left we get $\ln(1-t)$. On the right, integrating term by term, we get $t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^4}{4}+\cdots$.

Comment: Ahh I see now it makes sense why you subtract $t$! I get it now, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.